# Cordova Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, gradle, phonegap

I'm using cordova @8.0.0, all requirements are installed and set.
E.g. android studio, android sdk, variables path, added android platform...etc.

when I use build the following error return:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
>
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
>
> Could not create plugin of type
> 'LibraryPlugin'. com/android/repository/api/Downloader

Please I'm not familiar with android studio nor gradle.

Can you please provide me with a detailed answer.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48839690/7189547)  answer..

Comment: Thanx but this answer is for cordova-browser platform. my issue is related to cordova-android platform.

Comment: I know, I've tried many times to remove platform and to added again
nothing changed. same error message