# Unable to install Cordova plugin barcode Phonegap (mac)

Tags: cordova-plugins, phonegap

I'm super new to cordova and phonegap. I need to install the Cordova plugin barcodescanner and I have tried to do so through the Terminal (mac) with the following line:

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-barcodescanner` as specified in this [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-barcodescanner).

However, I get an error that I can not solve. I've read many other posts, and haven't found a solution for my case.

My error:

```
(node:1721) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Cannot 
find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-plugin-barcodescanner". Please 
try adding it again.
at new PluginInfo 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova- 
common/src/PluginInfo/PluginInfo.js:367:15)
at PluginInfoProvider.get 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova- 
common/src/PluginInfo/PluginInfoProvider.js:35:32)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova- 
lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:177:51
at _fulfilled 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova- 
lib/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova- 
lib/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova- 
lib/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova- 
lib/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova- 
lib/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
 (node:1721) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise 
 rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an 
 async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise 
 which 
 was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
 (node:1721) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise 
 rejections 
 are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not 
 handled 
 will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

These are my specs:
iOS: 10.13.4
Phonegap: 0.4.5

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out after many days and trials.
Basically what I did was create a new project from scratch, using CLI. Then I followed step by step [this documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/). When I got to the "plugin" section, I added the plugin I wanted with the following line:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-barcodescanner
```

Hope this helps other people.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

1. *https://github.com/hypery2k/cordova-barcodescanner-plugin* Try to use full url for installing plugin.

or

2.Set `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="0.7.4" />` to config.xml and try run `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-barcodescanner` with your cmd.

If it doesn't work try to run command `npm install cordova-plugin-barcodescanner`.  (if your command already add some files to plugin folder, remove it and run it again.)

Check the path you are trying to install plugin, it must be something like *C:/Desktop/Application/www/plugin/*

Be sure that your config.xml have:

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*" mode="merge">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
</config-file>
```

Comment: Hi proofzy! Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately, none of the above worked :(

Comment: When I tried the first option I get an error that says: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/hypery2k/cordova-barcodescanner-plugin via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect." plus many other lines.

Indeed my confi.xml did not have that line. I added it then ran, and I got this error: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-barcodescanner@0.7.4 via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect."

Comment: The path is correct, I am inside my plugins folder. I also added the config-file target, which I didn't have either, and it still doesn't work. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Try to [re-adding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48839690/7189547) platform android

Comment: Before re-adding platform android, find path \plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\plugin.xml if it's there, open plugin.xml and remove line `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera">`

Comment: I have no such path.

Comment: I found [issues](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/418) with barcodescanner, obviously they have a lot of problems with the plugin